# Load java maven dependencies with java classloader

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader

I tried to load dependencies with java -> https://hasteb.in/uzozibix.gradle but I always get a ClassNotFoundException. Why?

(Example: https://hasteb.in/yegoweho.java <- Netty Library)

Thank you <3

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you attempting to build a dependency management tool like maven/gradle? Or are you attempting to use a dependency management tool?

Comment: No. I want to write a Java System in which i don't want to compile all my dependecies. I want them to be installed by starting up my System.